# Parse Json In Java How to read Inner Value

Tags: java, json

Very New with `Java Development` Parsing `JSON` in `JAVA` Here is my `Code`.

```
package com.zenga.control;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

public class Start {

    public String readUrl(String urlString) {
        String jsonString = null;   
        try {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            GetMethod get = new GetMethod(urlString);
            client.executeMethod(get);
            jsonString = get.getResponseBodyAsString();
        }catch(Exception e) {

        }
             return jsonString;
    }

    public void getAddAsBeanObject()    {
        try {
        String jsonString =  new Start().readUrl("http://myDomain/JsonZ.json");     
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonString);        


        System.out.println(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
          }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Start().getAddAsBeanObject();
    }
}
```

As I successfully Read Value in `JSONObject` and it also showing all `JSON` String on console But How can i Get Value For `ID` and `UID` and `DURATION` ?
Here The `JSON`String the i read in `System.out.println(obj);`

```
{
  "Demo": {
    "CONTENT": [
      {
        "ID": " 283 ",
        "UID": " 87897bc8-ae9b-11e1-bdcf-123141042154 ",
        "DURATION": "Full"
      },
      {
       "ID": " 283 ",
        "UID": " 87897bc8-ae9b-11e1-bdcf-123141042154 ",
        "DURATION": "Full"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can be used to *iterate* the JSON objects inside the JSON array 'CONTENT', using [`.get(java.lang.String)`](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) as documented, to pull the value out of the `JSONObject`.

I have only demonstrated how to get the `ID` but the same logic applies to the other values.

```
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonString);
JSONArray content = obj.getJSONObject("Demo").getJSONArray("CONTENT");

java.util.Iterator<?> iterator = content.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(o);
    System.out.println(o.get("ID"));
    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is a sample code to reach the array`s inner objects specific to pattern you have provided.

```
String str = "{"+
      "\"Demo\": {"+
        "\"CONTENT\": ["+
         " {"+
        "\"ID\": \" 283 \","+
        "\"UID\": \" 87897bc8-ae9b-11e1-bdcf-123141042154 \","+
        "\"DURATION\": \"Full\""+
         " },"+
          "{"+
        "\"ID\": \" 283 \","+
        "\"UID\": \" 87897bc8-ae9b-11e1-bdcf-123141042154 \","+
        "\"DURATION\": \"Full\""+
         " }"+
        "]"+
      "}"+
    "}";

try {
    JSONObject jsr = new JSONObject(str); // JSON object with above data
    JSONObject demo = jsr.getJSONObject("Demo"); // get Demo which is a JSON object inside jsr.
    JSONArray content = demo.getJSONArray("CONTENT");// get CONTENT which is Json array inside Demo
    for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) { // iterate over array to get inner JSON objects and extract values inside
        JSONObject record = content.getJSONObject(i); // each item of Array is a JSON object
        String ID = record.getString("ID");
        String UID = record.getString("UID");
        String DURATION = record.getString("DURATION");
    }
}
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: Above code is specifc to org.Json API. Find appropriate methods in library you are using for Json handling

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop that iterates through the Json Object and access each of the element

```
for(/**loop until the counter reaches the size of the json object**/)  {

    //Access each element based on the ID as below.

    System.out.println(Demo.CONTENT[CurrentCounter].ID); //here CurrentCounter is index
    System.out.println(Demo.CONTENT[CurrentCounter].UID); ..... //read through all ids

}
```

Comment: How can i get how much objects are there ? like now in the `content` only `2` objects ?

Comment: Probably there should be some way like Demo.CONTENT.length, tried in Ajax response. Have to try the way like...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use the 'get' Method on the JSONObject. If you don't know which key to look for, I suggest using a Method that returns all available keys, like the one called 'keys'. With these values, you could then traverse down in you structure. See here:
http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess GSON will be a big help for you.
See here [Parsing json object into a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565862/parsing-json-object-into-a-string/16730531#16730531)

There is a samplecode as well

Answer (score -1):

Create a class which have variables you want to read from json string.And Gson will handle the rest.

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Example usage:

```
//convert the json string back to object
DataObject obj = gson.fromJson(br, DataObject.class);
```

Comment: First Review the Question m not looking how to parse there is some issue while parsing.